# image size that would fit width in android

Tags: android

I am fairly new to android dev and something keeps tripping is dealing with sizes and width.
I was wondering which image sizes do I need to have my image fit like the one below[image]

Wondering what sizes the image should be in.
hdpi
mdpi
xhdpi
xxhdpi

Looking for a pixel value

Comment: If you want the image to look good you should consider to have different images for different screen densities, but if the image is loaded from a server is different.

Answer (score 0):

The better answer will be on this page :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You will learn how to support multiple screen size on Android.

To summarize, the main rules are the following :

1. The *baseline* is mdpi : it's the resolution on which you should base your calculation
2. *baseline* is 160dpi
3. *hdpi* = **1.5** * *baseline*
4. *xhdpi* = **2** * *baseline*
5. *xxhdpi* = **3** * *baseline*

So if your picture should have a size of 150px at 160dpi resolution, you should create a 225px picture for *hdpi* screens and 300px picture for *xhdpi* screens.

Last advice : you should try to make your picture only when you understand how multiple screens support works. Density is the more important notion to understand correctly. Everything is described here : [Terms and concepts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms)

Answer (score 0):

You can fit it to parrents with a.k.a. Root layout to this activity and give it some margin for example about 10dp in your case:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android" />
```